# UISwitch customization

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

Because the the UISwitch is not so easy to customize i decide i wanna build one alone.
that works pretty good except for one thing. i was subclassing UIView when i was building it
and now i dont have the "ValueChanged" control that i need for the Interface builder.
can some1 tell me how can i add ControlEvents to my custom control ??

thank you very very much !

Comment: From the FAQ: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer." See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for more information.

Comment: yeah i figure that out , thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved i should have inherit from UIControl and not UIView